# Weird behavior of std::pair second when returned from a function

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

```
#include<boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/unordered_set.hpp>
using namespace std;

typedef boost::unordered_map<string, boost::unordered_map<string,     boost::unordered_set<string>>> nfa;
const boost::unordered_map<string, boost::unordered_set<string>>&    
get_second(const std::pair<string, 
           boost::unordered_map<string, boost::unordered_set<string>>>& p)
 {return p.second;}


int main()
{
   nfa a;
   a["A"]["0"] = {"B", "C"};
   a["A"]["1"] = {"B"};
   a["B"]["0"] = {"B"};
   a["B"]["1"] =  {"C"};
   cout << "Printing using direct reference" << endl;
   for (auto tr_table : a)
   {
     for (auto tr : tr_table.second)
      cout << tr_table.first << " " << tr.first << " " <<     tr.second.size() << endl;
  }
  cout << "Printing using function get_second" << endl;
  for (auto tr_table : a)
  {
    for (auto tr : get_second(tr_table))
      cout << tr_table.first << " " << tr.first << " " << tr.second.size() << endl;
  }
 return 0;
 }
```

For the same unordered_map, using tr.second returns the correct number of rows but using get_second returns a new map element with no elements.
What is the reason for this behavior?

I am using g++ 5.3.1 on Ubuntu.

PS: The behavior is same when std::unordered_map is used.

Comment: You're copying a lot of maps around.

Comment: I am not worried about the copying that goes on but I would like to understand why the two for loops behave differently. Is there a way to avoid the copying?

Comment: Visual Studio raises debug exceptions for the iterator derferencing in the in the inner loop. (using `std::` versions).

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to mention, I am using g++  5.3.1 on ubuntu.

Comment: @prasannak "Is there a way to avoid the copying?". Use `for( const auto& tr_table : a )` and something similar for the other loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `get_second` method parameter doesn't match the loop iterator in terms of constness... update as follows (note const string in pair) and it works:

```
get_second( const std::pair<const string,
    unordered_map<string, unordered_set<string>>>& p )
```

Answer (score 6):

`get_second` takes a pair of the wrong type, with a non-`const` key.

Therefore a converted temporary is constructed and you are returning a reference to this temporary.

All bets are off after that.

Comment: I would like to point out at this juncture that this problem and confusion has been caused (at least in part) by `auto`. If you'd listed the types (perhaps behind a `typedef`) in the first place rather than allowing deduction, you'd have seen a failure much earlier. Although, to be fair, the true culprit here is implicit conversions.

Comment: which, by the way, is how I spotted it... as I was simplifying the types...

Comment: `nfa::value_type` would have been best.

Comment: Another problem is in writing types by hand and not using member type aliases whch map provides for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the type mismatch.
@Revolver Jinx - Can you please point out some documentation that shows using the type aliases that map provides.

Comment: @prasannak Here you can see [`value_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html). And here is [C++ standard library concept of Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container). In short `value_type` is what actually stored inside container

Answer (score 2):

Be noted that `std::unordered_map`'s `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>` (it's **const Key**), so your `get_second()`'s parameter is wrong.

You can simply change to `get_second(const nfa::value_type& p)` to get correct behavior.